# windows settings closes down immediately after launching

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, default-settings

windows settings closes down immediately after launching.  I can open many settings windows(apps, privacy, devices, etc.except for accounts) by going around the home settings page, but going back to home or main accounts page closes it again.  have tried sfc and dsim cmd prompts, system restore, safe mode, and probably some other stuff forgotten. I assume it has something to do with accounts so created a new one, same issue.  running 1909 win10pro for workstations.  haven't noticed any other issues and it is more annoying than limiting.  was thinking about just forcing v.2004 but would like to fix this first.  any help???

Answer (score 0):

> have tried SFC and DISM cmd prompts, system restore, safe mode. created a new one, same issue.

Now run Windows 10 Repair Install (should keep V1909 at this point).

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally. Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with.

Once done, you may choose to upgrade to V2004 if you wish